# Something weird is going on in this comment

Tags: support, comment

Could someone please tell me how I can fix or delete my second comment to Berci's answer in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211589/the-geometric-boundary-of-a-manifold)?

Comment: For the people who are wondering what exactly was this about (and are unable to view deleted comments - which only mods can do), I've tried to replicate the situation [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox/4479#comment22353_4479). You can see that the comments go too far to the right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've deleted the comment. It happened because you had an unpaired dollar sign `$` which forced a long part of the comment be treated as a math environment. This made it run past the page boundary.

In the future, it suffices to flag the question/answer for moderator attention with a request to delete your comment.

Comment: Thanks. I knew that's why it happened, I just couldn't get to the edit link. I will flag for attention in future.